# Automatic failover for multiple DCs in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Does Datastax provide a native way to handle automatic failover for multiple DCs via the driver?

I could not find anything on the official Datastax website but found this [cassandra-dcaware-failover](https://github.com/adejanovski/cassandra-dcaware-failover) project on Github

Comment: how do you want the driver to act with a failover? It will already send queries to other DC if local DC unavailable

Comment: @ChrisLohfink You mean the default Datastax driver already does that? If so, how do you configure which DC is primary and which one should be used for failover?

Comment: look at https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/load_balancing/, set DCAware LB policy and you will get behavior you want (set DC in builder). Wrap with TokenAware for better performance, mostly with CL.ONE. Theres the obvious issues if you use LOCAL_QUORUM for consistency though that the 2nd DC wont give you consistency when the DC fails. If you need that you would want EACH_QUORUM to be safe on DC failure. CL.LOCAL_ONE/ONE though your gtg.

Comment: Ah thanks. For the CL DC failure issue that you've brought up, did you have it the other way around? That is, if I use ***EACH_QUORUM*** CL, that will error out as the write will fail on the failed DC. (You mentioned `LOCAL_QUORUM`). Therefore ***LOCAL_QUORUM*** should be used, and not ***EACH_QUORUM*** to be  safe on the DC failure. Is that correct?

Comment: each_quorum will fail when dc goes down, but queries made to it with local_quorum before the DC goes down may not of been replicated to the other DC, so querying to the other DC with local_quorum you will lose the assumed consistency. which is why it might be good idea to set allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel false if using LOCAL_ consistencies. Normal QUORUM might be good option if want to get data to other DC on normal but not fail with EACH depending on setup (ie non-vnodes can ensure quorum works)

Comment: Thanks. Just want to clarify 2 of yours points, though. 1) If using LOCAL_CL, `allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel` should be set to `true`, not `false`, correct?  2) Just want your take on this, using `QUORUM` or `EACH_QUORUM` makes the data more consistent between data centers but it would make the whole cluster less available, correct? Assuming 2 datacenters with `RF=3`,  `QUORUM` would require 5 nodes to respond, and `EACH_QUROUM` would require 4 nodes. Thus, it makes the cluster less available?